# sort data by date in %c format in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, datetime

Dataframe column :

```
Fri Jan 01 03:53:00 IST 2021

Sun Jan 03 03:44:14 IST 2021

Mon Jan 18 11:22:33 IST 2021

Sun Jan 17 03:54:41 IST 2021

Sat Feb 13 11:42:38 IST 2021

Tue Feb 16 03:51:25 IST 2021

Sun Feb 07 10:44:19 IST 2021

Sun Feb 07 11:35:08 IST 2021

Sun Jan 10 10:45:11 IST 2021
```

Desired output :
Sort the column by date and time in ascending order

I have tried :

```
data.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=True)
```

Result :

It returned column sorted by Day in Fri,Mon,Sat,Sun,Thu,Tue,Wed
how to rectify this?

Comment: Try changing the column to datetime first, e.g. `data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])`, and then sorting

Comment: But that would eliminate the time factor out of it , i want both the time and date to be in the output

Comment: no, pd.to_datetime does not remove time. it will throw a warning though, `IST` is ambiguous (use a proper time zone name instead to avoid/satisfy the warning).